# How can I force Thunderbird to compact my IMAP folder after running filters?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I have a bunch of Thunderbird emails that distribute my email from my Inbox to a bunch of IMAP and local folders. Unfortunately, since this is IMAP, no message is *actually* moved: messages get copied and the removal of the original is delayed until Thunderbird decides to compact folders (e.g. when I hit File → Compact Folders).

In an absolutely shocking turn of events, I have a smart mobile device, and thus more than one email client accesses the same inbox. It's bad enough that only one client can run filters, I don't also need to wait for Thunderbird to decide it's compact o' clock.

As a result, I need Thunderbird to compact folders as soon as it is done fetching my emails and running filters on it, no matter what.

How can I do that?

Comment: As a workaround you can use [Xpunge](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/xpunge/) to compact your IMAP folders on a timer.

Comment: Are you talking to yourself in the second person? Was about to comment that Xpunge is about the closest you can currently do and got very confused.